# IIS Redirect page using the hash tag

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7

I have two rules in my web.config the rule name InboundRule is working and Redirect to the correct PDF file. But the second rule with the trailing page number is not it looks like they both are hitting the InboundRule and not adding the page number to open the PDF File

> Is there a way to match on the page number and open the file to the correct page?

```
<rule name="InboundRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cars\/\/(\w+)\/index.html" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}.pdf" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
        </rule>


        <rule name="InboundRuleTrailingPageNumber" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html(\w+)" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html(\w+)" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                 <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}.pdf#page={R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
        </rule>
```

Updated Rule is still not working the only rule working is cars LandingPage.

```
 <!--Cars LandingPage-->
<rule name="PatientGLInboundRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="cars\/model\/(.*)\/index.html" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cars\/model\/(.*)\/index.html" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}-File.pdf" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
<!--Cars LandingPage -->
<!--Cars Page Number within URL -->
<rule name="CarsInboundRulePageNumberInURL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="cars\/model\/(.*)\/(.*)\/index.html" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cars\/model\/(.*)\/(.*)\/index.html" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}-File.pdf#page={R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
<!--Cars Page Number within URL -->
<!--Cars Trailing Page Number -->
<rule name="CarsInboundRuleTrailingPageNumber" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="cars\/model\/(.*)\/index.html#(.*)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="cars\/model\/(.*)\/index.html(.*)" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}-File.pdf#page={R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
<!--Cars Trailing Page Number -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your url rewrite rule, I found you have added the  negate="true" in the `InboundRuleTrailingPageNumber` url rewrite condition.

I means if the url match `cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html(\w+)`, it will make the url work.

I suggest you could try to remove the  `negate="true"` and try again.

More details, you could refer to below rules:

```
<rule name="InboundRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <rule name="InboundRuleTrailingPageNumber" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html(\w+)" />

                 <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}.pdf#page={R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
        </rule>
             <match url="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="cars\/\/(\w+)\/index.html" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}.pdf" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
        </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was related to the order of the rules. Once I corrected the order it all started to work.